# Metric showing higher value in blended data when date range comparison is added

Tags: google-cloud-storage, looker-studio

I have two data sources in Google cloud storage buckets. I am blending them in Google data studio as follows:

[image: Snapshot of blend configuration]

I have created a simple table chart which is working fine:
[image]

But when I set `Comparison date range` option to `Previous period`, the cost numbers displayed in the same table go haywire but the summary row which displays the total cost is fine. I don't observe this issue if the data is not blended.

[image: Google Data Studio visualization with Comparison data range enabled]

Comment: Can you share the data source and the report?

Comment: You may find interesting this [article clarifying how data blending works](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en).

Comment: Can you display your data sources from Cloud Storage correctly,  when not blending?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable "Comparison data range" it only show comparable data (that means, data that can be comparable with something).

Since your data source probably contains rows of a dates that doesn't have a relative row to compare with (the previous period), that data is filtered out from your visualization.